# Silverlight: URL parameter in query string escaped

Tags: silverlight, url

in Silverlight 5:

```
var uri= new Uri("http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=xyz&cb=http://localhost:19000/callback?bla=blu")
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri);
```

lands my browser at:
http://www.last.fm/api/auth?api_key=xyz&cb=http://localhost:19000/callback%253Fbla=blu

Note how the "?" of the URL in the callback parameter gets escaped to %253F - even though, if I look at uri.ToString() in the debugger, it's not escaped.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Many thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no answer, but if anyone stumbles across the same issue, here's what I tried and what I finally did:

First, I attempted to use HtmlPage.Window.Eval() to execute javascript which would navigate to that URL. Again, the ? was escaped even though URL.ToString() didn't escape it.

So what I finally did - could have thought of it earlier, really ;P - was to change my callback handler to follow a REST like format. Instead of:

```
http://localhost:19000/callback?bla=blu
```

it now listens at:

```
http://localhost:19000/callback/bla=blu
```

and takes the parameter value out of the path. No question mark involved anymore, problem solved.